# Genymotion alternative with the same features

Tags: windows, gratis, react, android-emulator

I am a developer and recently started working with `React-Native` to develop mobile app.

Those started using `Genymotion` as emulator. But there is some issue with `Genymotion`.

First off the emulator dose not always start, second its too slow (no matter how much I increase the RAM)

Now some of you may think that I have a bad PC and that why I will also put my PC specification here for you to see.

```
CPU:Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3820 CPU @ 3.60GHz   3.60 GHz
Ram:16GB
GPU:GTX 1070
Windows:10
```

What I want is a free personal use software that can work as an emulator with visual studio code.

Comment: Maybe on of those at the end of [this page](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/emulators)? I haven't tried them, so I cannot give a clear recommendation. There are also some Docker-based solutions out there missing from the list.

Comment: I could already search on google and test out many software that are similar. But That takes a lot of time and I really want 100% answer instead.

Comment: Genymotion bases on Virtualbox which is well working virtualization software. Make sure you have enabled all available virtualization functions in your BIOS.As alternative you can try official Android emulators from Android SDK.

Comment: Alen, I'm fully aware a clear recommendation is much to be preferred – especially if it gives all the necessary details. I cannot give such an answer, but didn't want to leave you empty-handed. While waiting for an answer, I thought having some hints would be better than "feeling ignored" – and in their concentrated form are better than having to gather it yourself from a web search. Of course you can wait for a complete answer if you prefer – but be aware it might take a while to appear.